# TooltipCompat crashing but I'm not using anywhere on my code

Tags: android, android-support-library

I just updated to support library 26 and released a beta and I've started getting a crash on crashlytics for something that as far as I know I'm not even using. I haven't ever seen the issue myself. Anyone else seen this?

Full stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
       at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipPopup.show(TooltipPopup.java:79)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.show(TooltipCompatHandler.java:155)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.access$000(TooltipCompatHandler.java:39)
       at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler$1.run(TooltipCompatHandler.java:53)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5280)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:963)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:758)
```

Edit: I might have finally reproduced it, long press on Android 4.4 on the overflow menu of the toolbar. Going to try to create a sample now.

Edit: It is definitely long press of overflow menu on toolbar that does it but I can't reproduce it with a simple project. I know have 2 apps crashing when this happens.

Comment: Are you using `android.support.v7.widget` in your project? If so try to update this library to the last version. Post your Gradle app`s file may help.

Comment: This is with the latest. And yes I use `RecyclerView`, `Toolbar`, lots of AppCompat views, etc, but I don't use Tooltip.

Comment: Are you sure that you have a reference to the Toolbar (ie did you do getViewById and pass the id to it)?

Comment: I do use the `Tootbar` in pretty much all my activities but this exception is for the `Tooltip` it seems. As far as I can tell `TooltipCompat` was added on version 26 and all I did was change the support library version from 26 alpha1 to 26.0.1 and released a new apk. I was only on 26 alpha1 for a few days so I don't know if the issue happened there.

Comment: Sorry I meant the TextView. Thats what the stacktrace says is null...

Comment: I use `TextView` everywhere of course, but if you see the full stacktrace and look at what is calling `setText` you'll see it is on the `Tooltip` code.

Comment: "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference" means that the TextView is null

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152671/discussion-between-midaslefko-and-casolorz).

Comment: Yes but the next line is `at android.support.v7.widget.TooltipPopup.show(TooltipPopup.java:79)` and the line inside `TooltipPopup` is `mMessageView.setText(tooltipText);` but `TooltipPopup` isn't my code so I can't fix it. Nor am I using `Tooltip` so I don't even know where to start to fix it.

Comment: Figured it out https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64594124

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Figured it out. Found this on the issue tracker https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64594124

Basically if you have your own tooltip.xml file it will conflict with the new tooltip of the design library.

Answer (score 0):

To add to casolorz solution: The problem is any `tooltip.xml` layout file.

I had a `NoSuchFieldError` after updating to Android Support Library 26.1.0 with the stacktrace posted below. But renaming my own tooltip.xml solved the issue as well.

My stacktrace for Google:

```
Exception java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: No static field message of type I in class Landroid/support/v7/appcompat/R$id; or its superclasses (declaration of 'android.support.v7.appcompat.R$id' appears in /data/app/com.mytowntonight.aviamap-1/base.apk)
    android.support.v7.widget.TooltipPopup.<init> (TooltipPopup.java:60)
    android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.show (TooltipCompatHandler.java:154)
    android.support.v7.widget.TooltipCompatHandler.onLongClick (TooltipCompatHandler.java:103)
    android.view.View.performLongClick (View.java:5265)
    android.widget.TextView.performLongClick (TextView.java:9240)
    android.view.View$CheckForLongPress.run (View.java:21240)
    android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:739)
    android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:95)
    android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:168)
    android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5845)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:797)
    com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:687)
```